# Codename One - Test Recorder: check if a component is completely shown without scrolling

Tags: codenameone

Using the Test Recorder of the Simulator of Codename One, how can I do the following tests?

1. The test has success if a given component (that has an assigned name) is shown in the current form.
2. The test has success if a given component (that has an assigned name) is completely shown in the visible part of the current form (without scrolling it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 you can do:

```
assertNotNull(findByName(componentName));
```

Number 2 is a bit trickier as there is no builtin assert for that. I would try something in this vain:

```
Component myCmp = findByName(componentName);
Container parent = myCmp.getParent();
Rectangle viewArea = new Rectangle(parent.getScrollX(), parent.getScrollY(), parent.getHeight(), parent.getWidth());
assertBool(viewArea.contains(myCmp.getX(), myCmp.getY());
assertBool(viewArea.contains(myCmp.getX() + myCmp.getWidth(), myCmp.getY() + myCmp.getHeight());
```